# Phonegap html input element onclick not firing

Tags: javascript, cordova, onclick

I'm working on a phonegap app and have a weird case where the onclick of an html input button isn't firing. The button does appear on the page. I click the button, see the shadow over the button so I know it's being clicked, but the function does not fire. The code is below. I took the same code and put it in jsfiddle where it works as expected. I tried setting it via jquery instead but same result.

```
console.log('making photo button');
var photoInput = document.createElement('input');
photoInput.type = 'button';
photoInput.value = 'Add Photo';
photoInput.onclick = function () {alert('photo button clicked');};
console.log(photoInput.onclick);
form.appendChild(photoInput);
```

Both console.logs fire, and the output of the second one is the onclick that was set above. To add to the weirdness, I create another input button below this one, with the same syntax but different onclick, and it works with no issues. The only difference is that this block is inside a switch case in a for loop, building the form dynamically, but the other button is created and appended after. Since the log statements show up, it isn't possible that the code isn't being reached.

Pre-Submission Edit: I just got this to work. After the loop and the other input button are created and appended, and the form is appended to the document, I run the following code.

```
var photoButton = document.getElementById('photoButton');
photoButton.onclick = function () {alert('photo button after clicked');};
```

I can work with this, but I'd like to understand why it wasn't working originally if anyone knows.

Comment: what happens if you set the onclick handler AFTER adding button to form instead of before ?

Comment: No change. It only seems to work once the element has been added to the document. For this one button :)